# Angular2 reuse route for edit/add

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm fairly new to Angular2 and I'm trying to edit and add elements to my database. To edit them I configured `elements/:id` so that goes off to the DB and pulls the element back. You can update it and all good. However when I try to add, in theory I could have exactly the same form but I wouldn't have an `id` because that's assigned by the backend so I don't really know if I am overloading the `element.detail.component` and I should be creating a new one just for add.

I also thought in adding a new route like `elements/addnew` and give it priority over the one above or just have a complete new one.

Updated:

My routing so far:

```
{ path: 'elements', component: ElementsComponent },
{ path: 'elements/:id', component: ElementDetailComponent },
```

If I use the option of the query string how could I make a distinction between a new element and pull all elements according to the route above?

Answer (score 4):

There is many ways you can achieve this with same component

**1st method**

use Query string to pass the value of id and if this query string is empty then just load the form with empty value and display the submit form button

**2nd method**

or you can simply pass id as 0 and scan for this value if it is 0 then load the empty form with submit button else display the details of the user

**3rd method**
use routing as

```
{ path: 'elements', component: myComponent},
{ path: 'elements/:id', component: myComponent},
```

and in **myComponent** scan for param `:id` if it is present then only load the user data else load the empty form

Comment: I like the 1st and 3rd methods but how could I resolve a possible conflict with the main route that pulls back all the elements? I updated the question with the current routing I have

Comment: just scan for param(:id) if it is not undefined then only  call the function to pull all the elements

Comment: this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    if(params['id'] !=undefined){
       this.id = +params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
       pullElement(this.id);
}
    });

Comment: OK, but at the moment I have two different components, one for all elements bound to /elements and one for the detail element so that's the question I have I don't know how to add a third route to configure the add. Does that make sense?

Comment: then change the route url for getting all elements to element-list or some other meaningful name and then add these two routes

Answer (score 2):

You can use **ActivatedRoute** from **@angular/router** to easily check in which mode you are (for example **new** or **edit** mode)

Example:

**recipe-edit.component.ts**

```
export class RecipeEditComponent implements OnInit {

id: number;
editMode: boolean = false;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        this.id = +params['id'];
        /**
         * Check if params has an ID property, 
         * if it has one, then this will actually be a string with the ID,
         * otherwise it will be undefined... By comparing it to null and checking if it is not null,
         * I am checking does it have the ID, because the ID will only be not undefined if we are 
         * in edit mode, because then an ID will be present.
         * 
         * So, if the ID indeed is undefined and therefore equal to null, this will return false because
         * I am checking the opposite and therefore, we are in new mode.
         */
        this.editMode = params['id'] != null;
    })
  }
}
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

`const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'recipes', component: RecipesComponent, children: [
        { path: '', component: RecipeStartComponent },
        { path: 'new', component: RecipeEditComponent },
        { path: ':id', component: RecipeDetailComponent },
        { path: ':id/edit', component: RecipeEditComponent }
    ]}
];`